# Node JS Request Printing nothing in console

Tags: node.js, api, request

I'm making an `post` call using the `nodejs` `requests` module. However, the `console.log` statements seems to be not working for either the `error` or the `response.body` that I am trying to get.

My `POST` request needs the following headers -

```
Accept : "application/json"
Content-Type : "application/json"
Authorization : Basic + Base64Encoded(username+password)
```

The `post body` is something like this

Body:

```
{
   "arg_1" : "a_string_key"
  , "arg_2" : "a_string"
  , "arg_3" : "a_string"
  , "arg_4" : "some_value"
  , "arg_5" : "some_string"
  , "arg_6" : "<yyyy-mm-dd>"
  , "arg_7" : "<yyyy-mm-dd>"
}
```

My code does nothing but send a `POST` request and checks if the `response.statusCode ==200`

Here is what I am doing

```
var int_user = "username";
var int_pass = "password";
var encoding = "base64"

var auth = "Basic" + new Buffer(int_user + int_pass).toString(encoding);

var headers = {
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Authorization": auth
}

var options = {
  url: 'URL_I_WANT',
  // method: 'POST',
  headers: headers,
  body : {
    "arg_1": "a_string_key",
    "arg_2": "a_string",
    "arg_3": "a_string",
    "arg_4": "some_value",
    "arg_5": "some_string",
    "arg_6": "<yyyy-mm-dd>",
    "arg_7": "<yyyy-mm-dd>"
  },
  json: true
}

console.log('Before request');

request.post(options, function(error, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  try {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(response.body);
      console.log('Success');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
});

console.log('After request');
```

The code runs without any glitch and I get the `before` and `after` request console statements. However the statements inside the requests do not appear in the console, which means my request is not going through. I am not able to understand this. Shouldn't an error come if there is an issue with the request itself? Any if the request is failing, why isn't the `error` printed out?

Comment: Can you try to print before the second if condition it could be that the response code isn't 200

Comment: Did that already. Also even if I pass an incorrect parameter in the `body` it runs same without printing the console, which should not be the case right.

Comment: Your code throws an error, you missed `body:` in the options object. After you fix it try this `request.post(options, console.log);` What is the output?

Comment: @Molda nothing, same output. Actually I didn't miss the `body` in my code. I missed it while adding in question.

Comment: @Bastien thanks for reminding. Added it now. I missed it while adding the question. The actual code has `body` mentioned.

Comment: Well, one suggestion is that the response has a statusCode which is not 200 and thus, your code will not print anything. Try adding a console.log(response) at the very beginning of your callback.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because your node process is auto-closed and it will exit before the async request to finishes (haven't looked into it but it might be something configurable). I've seen such set-up on repl.it for example.

To overcome this(if not configurable), you could wrap your code in an async function and use the request-promise to call await request.

```
var request = require('request-promise-native');


var int_user = "username";
var int_pass = "password";
var encoding = "base64"

var auth = "Basic" + new Buffer(int_user + int_pass).toString(encoding);

var headers = {
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Authorization": auth
}

var options = {
  url: 'https://google.com',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: headers,
  body : {
    "arg_1": "a_string_key",
    "arg_2": "a_string",
    "arg_3": "a_string",
    "arg_4": "some_value",
    "arg_5": "some_string",
    "arg_6": "<yyyy-mm-dd>",
    "arg_7": "<yyyy-mm-dd>"
  },
  json: true
};

console.log('Before request');

async function main() {
  try {
    const response = await request.post(options);
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      console.log(response.body);
      console.log('Success');
      process.exit();
    }
    console.log(`Bad statusCode:${response.statusCode}`);
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

main();
```

you can check-out the code below

[a link to the code above, working on repl.it](https://repl.it/@rluncasu/ImpureTiredMining)

Comment: I am getting an error - cannot find the `request-promise-native` module. :(

Comment: you need to install it first : npm install request-promise-native --save

Comment: Yeah I did that already. Since I was using TS, I installed the `@types/request-promise-native`, and imported it

Comment: I don't use typescript but as far as I know installing the types definition doesn't mean you've installed the module, I believe you still need to npm install.

Comment: The @types/* modules simply provide type definitions. You must install the actual library, `npm install --save request-promise-native`, in order to import it for use. Installing `@types/request-promise-native` merely provides nice intellisense.